# Pub/Sub Redis - Communication between NodeJS servers

Tags: node.js, redis, publish-subscribe

I am planning to use Redis pub/sub feature on my two NodeJS servers what needs to communicate with each other.

Lets have servers A and B:

I will make A as publisher "a" and B as publisher "b", then A will subscribe to "b" and B will subscribe to "a".

But there is problem. What if A disconnect? How will B recognize it? Will it fire some error? If not, how to achieve it?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Redis can do Pub/Sub

Answer (score 0):

Where is redis running?  It sounds like your two servers will each publish to one queue and subscribe to another.  It doesn't matter if either of them connect to or disconnect from redis, but if there is a problem with a queue you are subscribed to, the client will get the `error` event (see https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis#error-handling--v26) and you can respond to that.

Comment: Redis Server runs normally as service on server. Yea but I need to inform subscribers if publisher disconnect.

Comment: I don't think Redis has that, it's intended that you should be able to disconnect.  Perhaps you can have your clients send a regular "heartbeat" and assume they have disconnected if it doesn't arrive? 
 Or maybe replace Redis with something like MQTT which supports "last will and testament" to help with a situation like that.